# I cant find the custom html block

Tags: block-editor

I cant find the custom html block in wordpress. Does it not automatically come with a custom html block or do I have to create my own? I look for it in the search but it doesnt come up. I will click to add a block and then ill type 'html' or 'custom' and the block doesnt come up. Is there a way I can add this block? I need it for iframes. The plugins i have installed do not work. Has anyone else come across this issue? Is it possibly disabled?

Comment: It does come with WP Core, so you might try a different theme or deactivating plugins to find out what is disabling it. It's also possible that you don't have the right permissions - check that you're a default Administrator role and not something custom.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on StackOverFlow.

This block is the legacy custom HTML and as far I know, it's hidden  but you

```
add_filter( 'widget_types_to_hide_from_legacy_widget_block','sof_hide_legacy' );
function sof_hide_legacy( $widget_id ){
    $widget_to_show = array( 'custom_html' );
    $widget_id = array_diff( $widget_id, $widget_to_show );

    return $widget_id;
}
```

Does this help you ?